# Eventlistener for 'mouseover' and 'mouseleave'

Tags: javascript, events, mouseevent, mouseover, mouseleave

I am trying to make each cell change colour when the mouse hovers above them and return it to the default colour when the mouse leaves. I only created the .container div with HTML while the other divs were created with JS loops so I'm finding it difficult to execute the code.

I am pretty sure I need to make the cells a variable outside the function but if that's the case I'm not sure how to do it. Can someone help?

```
``let container = document.getElementById("container");


function makeRows(rows, cols) {
  container.style.setProperty('--grid-rows', rows);
  container.style.setProperty('--grid-cols', cols);
  for (c = 0; c < (rows * cols); c++) {
    const cell = document.createElement("div");
    cell.innerText = (c + 1);
    container.appendChild(cell).className = "grid-item";
  };
};

makeRows(16, 16);

var gridCells = document.querySelectorAll(".grid-item"); 

gridCells.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
  gridCells.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
});

gridCells.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
  gridCells.style.backgroundColor = '';
});``
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the event listener in the loop if you can only use javascript. Or you could just use css `.grid-item:hover {background-color: black;}`

```
let container = document.getElementById("container");


function makeRows(rows, cols) {
  container.style.setProperty('--grid-rows', rows);
  container.style.setProperty('--grid-cols', cols);
  for (c = 0; c < (rows * cols); c++) {
    const cell = document.createElement("div");
    cell.innerText = (c + 1);
    container.appendChild(cell).className = "grid-item";
    cell.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
      cell.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
    });
    cell.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
       cell.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
    });
  }
};

makeRows(16, 16);
```

Comment: You're a legend. Thanks, heaps.

Comment: the challenge was to use Javascript to manipulate the HTML DOM so I didn't want to use CSS. But yea definitely it would be much easier that way

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if this seems like a dumb suggestion, but why not use the css:hover property for this?

```
.grid-item:hover {
  background-color: black;
}
```

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp

Comment: Hey, the challenge was to use Javascript to manipulate the HTML DOM so I didn't want to use CSS. But yea definitely it would be much easier that way.